# Could you pressurise a container to stop an internal liquid from moving?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

If you have a sealed container partially-filled with water and then flip it upside down, the water will fall to the base under gravity. Would it be possible to increase the internal gas pressure sufficiently to stop this from happening? As in, could you have a gas pressure exert enough force onto the water to keep it from moving? Obviously would need a very strong container etc.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Have you gotten any ideas of your own on this? Please edit them into the question :)

Comment: No.  This would not be possible.

Comment: @ChetMiller, it would only be possible if the pressure exceeds the critical pressure.  Of course, at that point, there is only one phase in the container.  And I note that there are some questions on this forum that are completely unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand why liquid flows to the bottom under the action of gravity. Air is less dense than water. Assuming they are immiscible, then the configuration where lower density fluid is at the top, is the configuration of lowest energy (under the constraints of the problem). Therefore the system seeks that configuration spontaneously. Obtaining a top heavy configuration where water sits on top of gas is possible $\textit{in principle}$, where pressure exerted by the gas just balances the weight of water column above, but this configuration is unstable, and the slightest perturbation (which are ever present in real experiments) will inevitably push the system to the most stable configuration.

However in the discussion above I have assumed that gravity is the dominant force on the two fluids. When this is not the case, you can have a configuration where water sits on top of air, for example in a partially filled capillary tube in which surface tension dominates over gravity.

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but your question reminded me of this brain teaser experiment. Take a large Mason jar, pickle jar, or any jar with a large opening. Remove the lid and fill the jar with water. Then take a fine mesh strainer and place it over top of the jar. Holding the strainer firmly against the top of the jar, quickly flip the two and prepare to have your mind blown! (warning...do this over the sink)

Answer (score 0):

If the water stays a liquid, no.  If however you increase the pressure high enough to cause a phase transition, and the container in not smooth then this would be possible.  But that pressure would need to be exceptionally high.